# iOS - open another app alert - example with dropbox

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, dropbox

I am using Dropbox SDK and everything is working and it's okay. 
I just noticed that when I have their app in phone that for first time 
when I tried to connect and upload file from my app I get alert popup with question "Open Dropbox app ...?, Ok, Cancel".

Now I it didn't show up anymore. It's good, I allowed it and it remembers and starts app immediately.

**My problem is that I want to test it when user taps Cancel. So is there a way how can I show the alert again? I tried uninstall my app and Dropbox app but for now without luck.**

Example of my code:

```
func shareFileToDropbox() {
    if !DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked() {
      DBSession.sharedSession().linkFromController(self)
    } else {
      self.activityView.hidden = false
      self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
      self.uploadFileToDropbox(self.fileName, filePath: self.audioFilePath)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try my suggestions ? I think one of them will help you with your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your app and then installing it again.

Comment: As I wrote I tried to delete my app and install it again without any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your app BundleID for this test ... iOS will recognise your app as a new one. (I mean, different app than the installed one.)

I think if you Reset the privacy settings, you can resolve it too.

```
Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy
```

Comment: I've tried to Reset Location and Privacy and it didn't help. It removed some privacy settings like Trust to my computer but not what I needed. Maybe change of BundleID can help but when I do that I must create Provision profile for that identifier and I think it's too complicated solution for this. I hope some simpler solution to this.

Comment: Can't you simply debug this feature on simulator?

Comment: I can't because I can't install Dropbox app to simulator.

Comment: I you can't do one of this above, try the "Cancel test" on another device is your only choice...